# Unable to open Android Device Monitor due to Java version in MacOS

Tags: android-studio

When I try to open Android Device Monitor, this shows up:

[image]

As far as I recall, I never had this problem until macOS Sierra. And I'm worried it will screw up my environment if I follow what the pop up says.

In case anyone has this problem and manage to get Android Device Monitor running, can you please share your solution?

**Note**:

- I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3

Comment: As long as `JAVA_HOME` is set to the version you want, I don't see a problem with anything

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks much! This would have been the accepted answer.